# Does response status code make sense for multiple media types for error status codes as per OpenAPI 3 (Swagger) spec

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor, openapi-generator, swagger-3.0

If we follow the OAS3 spec for Response [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#responses-object) we can see that each response status code can have multiple media types and each media type in turn has a schema particular to it.

**UseCase :** For example oas3 example below, we can see 200 has a binary stream response but 400 has 3 media-types:application/json, application/xml, text/plain.

So is the client expected to request accept-type header with all the media-types mentioned below. How can we have specific media-type for 400 response code, or basically how we can convey to the REST Service to respond with media type as application/xml when its a 400 bad request and if 200 is returning a binary stream.

Does this OAS3 response multiple media-type make sense for Client/Server Errors. If yes then whats the accept-type set for expecting, say "application/xml" for 400 bad request.

Please refer the below swagger UI snap. Where we see a drop-down for the media-types for error code as well. But when we try out executing the rest operations, the accept header is only populated as per the 200 status code's media-type

[image]

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: "1.0"
  title: Resource
  description: Resource service
paths:
  /resource:
    get:
      summary: getResource
      description: getResource
      operationId: get-resource
      responses:
        "200":
          description: a binary document to be returned
          content:
            application/octet-stream:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
        "400":
          description: Bad Request
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error400Element"
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error400Element"
            text/plain:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error400Element"
        "500":
          description: Internal Server Error
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error500Element"
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error500Element"
            text/plain:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error500Element"
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8088/
components:
  schemas:
    Error400Element:
      type: object
      required:
        - name
      properties:
        name:
          type: string
        number:
          type: integer
    Error500Element:
      type: object
      properties:
        number:
          type: integer
        flag:
          type: boolean
```

**EDIT :** modified the OAS3 spec and the SwaggerUI

Comment: I can see a breakthrough only if the client sends accept headers with all the possible media-types that the service can provide. But in that case as well, does OAS3 spec provide some way to tell that the service can have a priority over the media types if there are multiple media types involded for the same status code. For ex priority can be like 400_status_code ==> json>xml>text